# Django: Editing as dataset like in admin site; Error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying a pretty simple thing. I have a database with customers. Now I am building a site where I choose one of the customers and edit the information about it. Exactly the same like in the admin pages where you choose one of your 'views' and you can change the values.

Unfortunately I am making somewhere a mistake.

Here my code:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from Customer import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^customerDetails/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.customer_details, name='customer_details'),
    url(r'^customerDetails/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.edit_customer, name='edit_customer'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
   customers = Customer.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'home.html', {'customers': customers})

def customer_details(request, pk):
   customerDetails = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=pk)
   return render(request, 'customerDetails.html', {'customerDetails':  customerDetails})

def edit_customer(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.first()
    customerDataSet = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditCustomerForm(request.POST, instance=customerDataSet)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('customer_details', pk=customerDataSet.pk)
    else:
        form = EditCustomerForm(instance=customerDataSet)

    return render(request, 'edit_customer.html', {'customerDataSet': customerDataSet, 'form': form})
```

**modely.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    someId = models.IntegerField()
    customerName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
#with some more fields 
class customerDetails(models.Model):
    customerName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
#with some more fields
```

**formy.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Customer

class EditCustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['someId', 'customerName']
```

**edit_customer.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Edit a customer{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Customer</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'customer_details' customerDetails.pk %}">{{ customerDetails.customerName }}</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Edit customer</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post</button>
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

I got the error :

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: Reverse for 'customer_details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['customerDetails/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
```

Can you help me to find the error im my code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. My **edit_customer.html** was wrong.

The line:

```
<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'customer_details' customerDetails.pk %}">{{ customerDetails.customerName }}</a></li>
```

should be instead:

```
<li class="breadcrumb-item">{{ customerDataSet.customerName }}</li>
```

Comment: The error was actually related to `<a href="{% url 'customer_details' customerDetails.pk %}">`. Here you should have replaced `customerDetails.pk` with `customerDataSet.pk`.

Comment: Yes, that true. It is the other solution. You corrected the code and I deleted the error without correcting it :-)